# Measurement error in nonlinear models, when can one ignore it? and what can one do about it?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, measurement-error

Suppose you know there is measurement error in your system but you don't have any idea what the variance is. In my specific case I have a nonlinear model

\begin{align}
y_i&=\epsilon_i f(\beta,x_i)
\end{align}

where $\epsilon_i$ is log-normally distributed with mean 1, and 
\begin{equation}
f(x,\beta)=\frac{\beta_1x}{1+\beta_2x}
\end{equation}

But we know $x$ and $y$ are measured with some error, which we know to be of the form
\begin{align}
x_i&=\eta_i x_i^*\\
y_i&=\eta_i y_i^*\\
y^*_i&=\epsilon_i f(\beta,x_i^*)
\end{align}

where $x^*_i$ and $y^*_i$ are the true variables and $\eta_i$ and $\zeta_i$ are iid lognormal with mean 1 and unknown variance (they have the same variance but not the same as $\epsilon_i$). Currently I have been completely ignoring the measurement error and using nls on the log transformed data. I am only concerned about the parameter estimates and not confidence intervals. $x$ and $y$ should be at least 4 or so orders of magnitude larger than the variance in either $\epsilon$ or $\eta_i$ and $\zeta_i$. I recognize that there is two forms of bias here. First the $\log$ transformation means that the error term in

\begin{align}
\log(y_i)&=\log(f(\beta,x_i)) + e_i
\end{align}

does not have mean zero, which creates bias (but possibly negligible because of the 4 or so orders of magnitude condition above), plus there is probably bias from the measurement error in general. My question is (1) how much can this bias affect the parameter estimates and (2) what can I do if this bias is large?

My idea was to generate data under this model via simulation under different variances in the measurement error and then see how much it affected the parameter estimates. Is there something better I can do?